# values of one tree match other tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am solving a few questions on Trees to prepare for tech interviews. I stumbled upon a problem to see if values of one tree ( subset ) match values of another tree ( main tree )

for eg

```
          3     is part of                4  
         / \    ----------->             / \
        7   9                           3   7
                                           / \
                                          8   9
```

I came up with the below solution.

```
public static boolean isSubset(TreeNode<String> subNode, TreeNode<String> mainNode){
    if(subNode == null)     
        return true;

    if(mainNode == null)
        return false;

    if(subNode.data.equals(mainNode.data)){
        return (isSubset(subNode.left,mainNode) && isSubset(subNode.right,mainNode));
    }else{
        return (isSubset(subNode,mainNode.left) || isSubset(subNode,mainNode.right)); 
    }
}
```

But this solution only checks if the nodes are in the same order ( root, left and right) as in the mainTree. 
What should i change in the above code so that I can check for each node in my subtree with each node of the main tree for a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, you don't care about the tree structure at all; you only need to test whether each element of the tree rooted at `subNode` is present in the tree rooted at `mainNode`. I suggest that you develop a predicate (let's call it `contains`) that tests whether a single value is in a tree. Then you can build on that:

```
public static boolean isSubset(TreeNode<String> subNode, TreeNode<String> mainNode){
    if(subNode == null)     
        return true;

    if(mainNode == null)
        return false;

    return mainNode.contains(subNode.data)
        && isSubset(subNode.left, mainNode)
        && isSubset(subNode.right, mainNode);
}
```

Comment: While this certainly works, it's a bit slow, because it doesn't take advantage of the tree structure of either subset.  It would be better to have a version of `contains()` that returns the node that contains `subNode.data`, instead of just `true`.  Suppose you assign this node to `x`.  You can then search just `x.left` (instead of the entire `mainNode`) for `subNode.left`, and likewise for `x.right` and `subNode.right`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - Yes, that would be a significant improvement.